# Proving that a limit does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the function 
$$f(x)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
  1 & x \gt 0 \\
  0 & x =0 \\
  -1 & x \lt 0
 \end{matrix}\right\}$$

What is $\lim_{a}f$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R},a \gt 0$?

It seems easy enough to guess that the limit is $1$, but how do I take into account the fact that $f(x)=-1$ when $x \lt 0$?
Thanks

Comment: If $a$ is positive, there is an open interval of positive reals that contains $a$, and $f$ is constantly $1$ on this interval. Now follow the solution suggested by Alex.

Comment: With limits, the only thing that matters is how $f$ behaves near $a$. Since $a > 0$, if we get close enough to $a$, all the numbers are positive and $f(x) = 1$ for any $x$ close enough to $a$. Thus the limit equals $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $a>0$, let $\delta=a$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, we have that 
$$|x-a|<\delta\implies x>0\implies f(x)=1\implies |f(x)-1|<\epsilon$$
hence $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=1$, as we have satisfied the definition of limit.

Answer (score 0):

Well for a>0, a/2 is between 0 and a, so all x in [a/2,b] with b>a have the property f(x) = 1. Moreover, the question asks you to find the limit for all a>0. You don't need to worry what the value of f is for x =< 0, only what it is for x>0.

Comment: Okay but if $a$ is close to $0$ then in a neighborhood of $a$ I will have negative $x$ values, and $f(x)$ will have a different result. Will it not matter?

Comment: No. If a > 0, then no matter how close a is to 0, a/2 will ALWAYS be between 0 and a. This is a property of the real numbers and is the main reason as to why the real numbers is different from the integers... because between ANY two real numbers b and c there is a real number (namely b+c)/2, whereas for the integers, this is not always true, e.g. there is no integer between 5 and 6.

Answer (score -3):

Here $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1$ & $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=-1$ both limit are not equal.

therefore limit is not exists

Comment: What you note is right; but does not answer the question. Please read the question before you'd answer. (I have been a victim of this disease myself. :)) BTW, I did not downvote.